# How to access a request parameter in EL

Tags: jsp, el

I'd like to check values of a `request` parameter in EL.

Supposing to have an url like `page.jsp?par1=test` I've tried something like:

```
<c:if test='{"test".equals(par1)} >
    [...]
</c:if>
```

But I've had no success.

So, how can I access a request parameter in EL?

Comment: Your EL syntax is wrong, EL always begins with a "$". So try something link `<c:if test="${param.par1==test}" .... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
<c:set var="test" value="yourValue"/>
<c:if test="${test==param.par1}">
  do what you want
</c:if>
```